# Java Battleship: invalid input is still sent to next method

Tags: java

I wrote a piece of code to implement a Battleship game.
One of its methods (pickRow) is meant to let the user pick a row in the playing field (5x5) to fire in. This method checks checks whether the user input is within the boundaries of the playing board (as mentioned 5x5) and if the user input is an integer (see try-catch statement).

However, the program gives an error as the user input is for example 444 (=invalid input). Although forcing the user to provide another number, the 444 is still transferred on to the next methods (playerAttempt & adaptBoardAfterAttempt), raising an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

How can I fix the code so that the invalid user input is no longer transferred to subsequent methods? For my code, see below.

Thanks,
Sander

```
public static int pickRow(int row) {
    //method to let the user pick a row
    //
    Scanner rowInput = new Scanner(System.in); 

    try {    //checks if user input is an integer by using try-catch statement
        System.out.print("Pick a row (1-5): "); 
        row = rowInput.nextInt();

        if (!isWithinBoundaries(row)) {    //checks if user input is within boundaries of the playing board
            System.out.println("That's outside the sea. Please provide a number from 1 to 5.");
            pickRow(row);         //asks for new user input because user input is outside boundaries of the playing board    
        } else {            
            row = row - 1;    //adjusts the value of row to correct for programming indices 
        }

    } catch (java.util.InputMismatchException e) {
        System.out.println("Sorry, invalid input. Please provide a number from 1 to 5.");
        pickRow(row);        //asks for new user input because input is not an integer 

    }              
    return row;             
}

public static int pickColumn (int column) {
    //method to let the user pick a column
    //
    Scanner columnInput = new Scanner(System.in);   

    try {    //checks if user input is an integer by using try-catch statement
        System.out.print("Pick a column (1-5): "); 
        column = columnInput.nextInt();

        if (!isWithinBoundaries(column)) {    //checks if user input is within boundaries of the playing board
            System.out.println("That's outside the sea. Please provide a number from 1 to 5.");
            pickColumn(column);         //asks for new user input because user input is outside boundaries of the playing board    
        } else {            
            column = column - 1;    //adjusts the value of column because java starts counting at 0, not 1 
        }

    } catch (java.util.InputMismatchException e) {
        System.out.println("Sorry, invalid input. Please provide a number from 1 to 5.");
        pickColumn(column);        //asks for new user input because input is not an integer   
    }              
    return column;             
}

public static void playerAttempt(int[] playerAttempt) {
    //method that incorporates player's picks of row and column into an attempt
    playerAttempt[0] = pickRow(row);
    playerAttempt[1] = pickColumn(column); 
}

public static void adaptBoardAfterAttempt (int[] playerAttempt, int[][] ships, int[][] board) {
    //adapts the playing board after a player attempt to indicate a hit (X) or a miss (0)
    if (isHit(ships,playerAttempt)) {
        board[playerAttempt[0]][playerAttempt[1]]=2;
    } else {
        board[playerAttempt[0]][playerAttempt[1]]=1;
    }
}
```

Comment: you're recursing. if the input is invalid, you just call `pickRow()` again. But you don't return the value returned from that recursive call - you return the bad valid entered BEFORE the recursive call. So effectively you say "this was a bad input, gimme a new one", then throw away that new (proper?) input and continue using the bad one.

Comment: In short, add `return` before your recursive calls.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, but I can't figure out where the return statement should be placed exactly. I tried to place it after the else-statement, but the program complains about a missing return-statement then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what worked for me (my comments start with ">>"):

```
public static int pickRow() {
        //method to let the user pick a row
        Scanner rowInput = new Scanner(System.in); 
        String response;
        int row;

        while (true) //>> loop is infinite as long as input is invalid.  As soon as it's valid, method returns, exiting the loop.
        {           
            //checks if user input is an integer by using try-catch statement
            System.out.print("Pick a row (1-5): ");
            response = rowInput.nextLine();
            try {
                row = Integer.valueOf(response);
            } catch (NumberFormatException e)
            {
                System.out.println("Sorry, invalid input. Please provide a number from 1 to 5.");
                continue;
            }

            if (!isWithinBoundaries(row))
            {    //checks if user input is within boundaries of the playing board
                System.out.println("That's outside the sea. Please provide a number from 1 to 5.");
            } else
            {                   
                row = row - 1;    //adjusts the value of row to correct for programming indices 
                return row; //>> row is valid, so return it
            }
        }
    }
```

Here's what I changed:

- I removed your argument `row`.  It doesn't need to be an argument passed to the method, since your `Scanner` retrieves the value for `row`.  Instead, I declared it as a method-level variable.
- I added a `String` variable called `response`.  I changed your code to retrieve this as the user's input, rather than `row`. (i.e., your `Scanner` uses `nextLine()` now rather than `nextInt()`.
- I placed the rest of the code in an infinite `while` loop and deleted your recursive `pickRow()` calls.  This way, the method just keeps asking for input until it's finally a valid response, at which point the method returns the row number.  In any other instance, the response is not valid and the loop continues.
- I rearranged your exception handling to catch a `NumberFormatException` when I try to convert `response` to an integer (to assign to `row`).  If an exception is thrown, it prints your error message and the loop `continue`s again.

In short, when the method is called, the program asks for 1 - 5.  If it's too big or small, `isWithinBoundries` catches it, and the program asks again.  If it's not a number, the `catch` block catches it, and the program asks again.  If it's a valid value, the method does your -1 procedure and returns the row.

I hope this helps!